# Have to Press "Enter" twice after a getline in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have googled this like crazy and have found a number of "solutions," along with forum posts from like 2001-2007 saying it's a "well-known bug" in Visual Studio...So why wouldn't it be fixed by now? I'm using VisualStudio 2013 (version 12).

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>

#undef max

using namespace std;

/*
TEST CASES:

*/



// START FUNCTION - Add Restaurant
void resto(vector<string> &restaurant)
{
    std::string resto_name;
    cin.ignore();
    //cin.clear();
    //cin.sync();
    std::getline (std::cin, resto_name,'\n');
    restaurant.push_back(resto_name);
}
// END FUNCTION - Add Restaurant

// START FUNCTION - Print Vector
void print_vector(vector<string> &restaurant)
{
    cout << endl << "Your Current Restaurants:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < restaurant.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << i + 1 << ". " << restaurant[i] << endl;
    }
}
// END FUNCTION - Print Vector



int main(void)
{
    srand(time(0));

    int menu;

    vector<string> restaurant; //Initialize Vector

    do {
        system("cls");
        cout << " -----------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "|     -:|:- Welcome to Restaurant Battle Royale! -:|:-      |" << endl;
        cout << "|-----------------------------------------------------------|" << endl;
        cout << "|  Please select an option by pressing 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6  |" << endl;
        cout << "|\t\t\t then press ENTER.\t\t    |" << endl;
        cout << "|-----------------------------------------------------------|" << endl;
        cout << "| 1 - Display all restaurants\t\t\t\t    |" << endl;
        cout << "| 2 - Add a restaurant\t\t\t\t\t    |" << endl;
        cout << "| 3 - Remove a restaurant\t\t\t\t    |" << endl;
        cout << "| 4 - Shuffle the vector\t\t\t\t    |" << endl;
        cout << "| 5 - Begin the tournament\t\t\t\t    |" << endl;
        cout << "| 6 - Quit the program\t\t\t\t\t    |" << endl;
        cout << " -----------------------------------------------------------" << endl;

        cout << "Option: ";
        cin >> menu;

        //OPTION 1
        switch (menu)
        {
        case 1:

            print_vector(restaurant);

            cout << endl;

            printf("Press any key to return to the main menu...");
            system("pause > nul");
            break;

            //OPTION 2
        case 2:
            cout << "\nPlease enter the name of the restaurant you'd like to add." << endl;

            resto(restaurant);

            break;

            //OPTION 3
        case 3:

            break;

        case 4:
            return 0;
        }
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    } while (menu != 6);


    return 0;

}
```

The problem I'm getting is in the "Add Restaurant" function. After input is given for the getline, you have to press enter twice. I've tried things like adding "\n" and "endl" to no avail. I'm tempted to think it's a bug with the compiler, but that would just be pathetic for this bug to last so long after so many years of development, right?

So it's gotta be my code. Can you help me spot what's wrong?

I have been stuck on this for HOURS, and I cannot move on because it's bugging me so much.

====================================================

References:

Microsoft's Solution to this from who-knows-when:
http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;q240015&ID=KB;EN-US;q240015
(After looking at the String file, it looks like they've applied this suggested change to the current version)

A solution I tried that worked for someone else but not for me:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/35262-visual-c-getline-bug/

Comment: `using std::cout; using std::cin; /* etc. */ using namespace std;` - it was so nice and then you ruined it with the last directive...! :'(

Comment: So is the using namespace std redundant? I'm pretty new to all this...

Comment: No, it's not redundant, but it makes the `using std::cout;` etc. before it redundant (since `using namespace std;` brings in the entire heck of the standard namespace, whereas `using std::foo;` only brings in `foo` from `std`). So, you better stick with the individual `using std::foo;` directives, it's less destructive.

Comment: Since you are using getline, you don't need the cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); at the end, as getline already discards the delim. Your code is waiting at cin.ignore for the delim char. So you can either remove the cin.ignore statement or use std::cin instead of the getline and keep the ignore statement.

Comment: What you say makes sense (if I understood correctly), but I ran into a lot of problems after deleting the using namespace std. I'd probably have to include a few more 'using std::foo;' things to fix it. Thanks, though

Comment: @sajas Thank you for the reply! I need to have input that can include spaces. Is there a way for 'std::cin' to do this? When I googled it, everyone said you have to use 'getline' if you want spaces in the string...

Comment: @remyabel It didn't even recognize my 'getline' without having the cin.ignore() before it. I couldn't input anything. When I Googled for a solution, members of this site told the enquirer to place a 'cin.ignore()' before the 'getline'...

Comment: @wad11656 sajas is correct...ignore my comment.

Comment: @sajas When I commented out 'cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');' at the end, it did function. (THANK YOU!)  But now if invalid input such as 'fjsdkla;' is given at the main menu in stead of a number, it goes into the "eternal loop" mode...Is there no way around this the way I want it to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@sajas is correct. The reason why you need `cin.ignore()` inside resto is because after `cin >> menu`, a stray linefeed is left in the stream. The subsequent `getline` extracts the linefeed and terminates immediately. `cin.ignore()` will extract and discard the stray linefeed, allowing `getline` to work correctly.

In actuality, the line that's causing a problem is:

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

All this does is extract and discard any characters up to the linefeed character, so it's completely unnecessary.

---

In order to catch bad input, you can do this:

```
    while (!(cin >> menu))
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cout << "Please enter a number.\nOption: ";
    }
```

If the extraction fails (because the user didn't input a number), you clear the error flag, discard any bad characters in the stream then ask for input again. It will loop until the user enters a number.

---

Per [@The Paramagnetic Croissant's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581793/have-to-press-enter-twice-after-a-getline-in-c/26581952#comment41780029_26581793), [`using namespace std;` is considered bad practice.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) I noticed that you are inconsistent with where you place `std::`. In general, if you opt to have a using directive, place it inside a function, so that it doesn't pollute the global namespace. It's better to get into the habit of typing `std::` everywhere, as it isn't that much typing.

You're including non-standard Windows headers, Windows.h and conio.h. Since you're not taking advantage of any API features, you don't need them.

Remove `printf`. You don't need it.

`system()` is extremely platform specific and frowned upon (although I don't have any sources to back this up.) Prefer `cin.get()` to `system("pause")` and remove `system("cls")` as this may irritate the user.

Inside `print_vector`, you're using `int` when you should be using `std::size_t` or preferably `std::vector<string>::size_type`. Your compiler may warn you about this:

```
main.cpp:56:23: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' 
                and 'size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
    for (int i = 0; i < restaurant.size(); i++)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Is there anyway to fail-check invalid input for the main menu then? (eg if 'fjdskla;' is input in stead of a # 1-6). It goes into an endless loop if invalid input is given at this point.

Comment: Lots of great advice--Thanks for taking the time to write that out for me (If people stopped down-voting my Q's, I could rep you). I tried to change my line to:
'void print_vector(std::vector<string>::size_type &restaurant)'
but got a "qualified name is not allowed" error. I think I misinterpreted how to implement your suggestion..

Comment: @wad11656 Yes, it should be `std::vector<string>::size_type i`.

Comment: kay well I'm a bit too daft to figure it out but everything else you said makes sense to me--Thanks a lot for the clear explanations!